# Parsing XML in python: selecting an attribute given that a child node has a specific attribute

Tags: python, xml

Given the xml

```
xmlstr = '''
<myxml>
    <Description id="10">
      <child info="myurl"/>
    </Description>
</myxml>'
```

I'd like to get the id of Description only where child has an attribute of info.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
a = root.find(".//Description/[child/@info]")
print(a.attrib)
```

and changing the find to `.//Description/[child[@info]]`

both return an error of:

```
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

I know that etree only supports a subset of xpath, but this doesn't seem particularly weird - should this work? If so, what have I done wrong?!

Changing the find to `.//Description/[child]` *does* work, and returns

```
{'id': '10'}
```

as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've definitely hit that XPath limited support limitation as, if we look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementPath.py#L242) directly (looking at 3.7 source code), we could see that while parsing the Element Path expression, only these things in the filters are considered:

- `[@attribute]` predicate
- `[@attribute='value']`
- `[tag]`
- `[.='value']` or `[tag='value']`
- `[index]` or `[last()]` or `[last()-index]`

Which means that both of your rather simple expressions are not supported.

---

If you really want/need to stick with the built-in `ElementTree` library, one way to solve this would be with finding all `Description` tags via `.findall()` and filtering the one having a `child` element with `info` attribute.

Comment: I don't need to stick with `ElementTree` - I'd tried lxml too, but found it slightly less intuitive to use...

Comment: @ChrisW yeah, with `lxml`, your expression `.//Description[child/@info]/@id` would work as-is. There is also `BeautifulSoup`, which could potentially be a more intuitive option. Check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, even wanting a specific value for the attribute works with lxml: `root.xpath("//Description[child/@info='myurl']")` :)

Comment: @ChrisW it is definitely a powerful tool. And, it is blazingly fast!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get those values as keys, which makes it a bit more structured approach to gather data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
wht =root.find(".//Description") 
wht.keys() #--> ['id']
wht.get('id')  # --> '10'
```